# Next call on Chain of Command in X++ D365 FO

Tags: c#, button, microsoft-dynamics, x++, chain

I'll try to explain my goal briefly. My code should display a NoYes pop up when I click on a button and a certain condition happens, If I press Yes the code keep going, if I press No it stops. I used a Chain of Command class, as an axtension of the  button on my form, This is my code:

```
[ExtensionOf(formControlStr(VendEditInvoice, OK))]
final class VendEditInvoice_OK_AzimutBenetti_Extension
{
    public void clicked()
    {
        IntentLetter_IT intentLetter;
        VendInvoiceInfoLine vendInvoiceInfoLine;

    Info(strFmt('%1, %2', vendInvoiceInfoLine.LineAmount, intentLetter.remainAmountMST()));
   

    if(vendInvoiceInfoLine.LineAmount >= intentLetter.remainAmountMST())
    {
        DialogButton diagBut;
        str strMessage = "Importo da decurtare al saldo della lettera di intento maggiore dell’importo residuo. Proseguire?";
        str strTitle = "Splafonamento";
        diagBut = Box::yesNo(
                strMessage,
                DialogButton::No,
                strTitle
                );
        if(diagBut == DialogButton::No)
        {
            //return;
            info('Operazione annullata');
            throw error('Operazione annullata');
        }

    }
    next clicked();
}
```

}

If I put the Return inside the second if, I get this error once I build the project: call to 'next' should be done only once and unconditionally.
I assume that's because if I press No, the code returns and the method next is never called, because if I delete Return and put for example an info, everything works fine. I tried with a throw error as you can see, but, even if it works, I think that is not the correct way to do it, cause there is no real error or exception, when I presso NO . How Can i do it in a different way that works?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use EventHandler and FormControlCancelableSuperEventArgs

Take a look at https://stoneridgesoftware.com/use-event-handlers-to-override-a-form-control-lookup-method-in-dynamics-365-finance-and-operations/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).